# How to get the public desktop folder path in XP (C++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, localization, windows-xp

I need a way to get the path of the public desktop folder that has to work on XP as well as the newer flavours of Windows and must be (human) language-independent. There doesn't seem to be a setting in the environment variables that covers this folder.

SHGetKnownFolderPath() only works in Vista and later, so I need to know if there's another function that will work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call SHGetSpecialFolderLocation with CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY

Comment: Actually, it turns out that SHGetSpecialFolderPath is more what I was after.

Comment: mingw doesn't seem to have this SHGetSpecialFolderLocation function, any idea why?